# Consuming REST API from Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, web-applications, rest

I'm building my first Rails App and I want it to consume everything from a REST API. What I want to do is to have Rails serve my web application as a frontend to my API. As far as I've read (I'm staring with Rails right now), Rails has a lot of potential with ORMs and direct access to database systems. My platform, on the other hand, is designed in such a way that every layer is accessed via a defined interface (in this case a REST API), so no databases are read from any client, but via their interfaces.

For example, my API exposes the following resource:

```
https://api.example.com/v1/users/feature-xxx [GET]
```

And I want my web app to have a page like:

```
https://example.com/feature
```

So the users will visit this URL and when logged in, the Rails app will request the data to generate this dynamic content from my API.

The question is:

- What are the necessary steps for my Rails Application to consume its *data* from a HTTP/Rest Backend? and,
- Is this a good design for a Rails app?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please mark Duke's answer as the right one? My answer is old and invalid in these times.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

ActiveResource is no longer being included in Rails 4.0.  Word is that it is barely maintained these days, and is difficult to customize for REST API endpoints that are not formulated according to the "Rails way".

After some research, I am heavily favoring using [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday). It includes support for utilizing different HTTP request adapters.  It can use EventMachine directly, or libraries like Typhoeus for when you decide to get concurrent.  It also supports Rack-like middleware for seamlessly including, say, authentication.

For a REST ORM in Rails that is easily configurable, the relatively new (about a year old) [Her](https://github.com/remiprev/her) looks very promising, and utilizes Faraday.

**Update**

I completely <3 [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).  So simple.  If you need ORM-style functionality, then you'll need a higher-level abstraction, but for simply consuming an API, you can't beat its simplicity.  It just does exactly what it's supposed to do without fuss, has sensible defaults, and has the  ability to set advanced options such as auth headers.

Comment: I'd also recommend `curb`. It's really fast, the fastest client i have seen

Answer (score 21):

I would highly recommend [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) for your requirement. My experience with it has been really good. Provided that the API you intend to consume is **really** REST, I don't think there is any cleaner design for consuming data through REST API. From it's README,

> ## Active Resource
>
> Active Resource (ARes)
>   connects business objects and
>   Representational State Transfer (REST)
>   web services. It implements
>   object-relational mapping for REST web
>   services to provide transparent
>   proxying capabilities between a client
>   (ActiveResource) and a RESTful service
>   (which is provided by Simply RESTful
>   routing in
>   ActionController::Resources).
>
> ## Philosophy
>
> Active Resource attempts to
>   provide a coherent wrapper
>   object-relational mapping for REST web
>   services. It follows the same
>   philosophy as Active Record, in that
>   one of its prime aims is to reduce the
>   amount of code needed to map to these
>   resources. This is made possible by
>   relying on a number of code- and
>   protocol-based conventions that make
>   it easy for Active Resource to infer
>   complex relations and structures.
>   These conventions are outlined in
>   detail in the documentation for
>   ActiveResource::Base.
>
> ## Overview
>
> Model classes are mapped to
>   remote REST resources by Active
>   Resource much the same way Active
>   Record maps model classes to database
>   tables. When a request is made to a
>   remote resource, a REST XML request is
>   generated, transmitted, and the result
>   received and serialized into a usable
>   Ruby object.
>
> ## Configuration and Usage
>
> Putting Active
>   Resource to use is very similar to
>   Active Record. It’s as simple as
>   creating a model class that inherits
>   from ActiveResource::Base and
>   providing a site class variable to it:
>
> ```
> class Person < ActiveResource::Base  
>   self.site = "http://api.people.com:3000/" 
> end
> ```
>
> Now
>   the Person class is REST enabled and
>   can invoke REST services very
>   similarly to how Active Record invokes
>   life cycle methods that operate
>   against a persistent store.
>
> ```
> # Find a person with id = 1 
> ryan = Person.find(1) 
> Person.exists?(1)  # => true
> ```
>
> As you can see, the methods are
>   quite similar to Active Record’s
>   methods for dealing with database
>   records. But rather than dealing
>   directly with a database record,
>   you’re dealing with HTTP resources
>   (which may or may not be database
>   records).

[Read more here...](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/master/README.rdoc)

Comment: I think Duke's answer should now be marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you decide to not use an HTTP client library like Farady or HTTParty, you can use open-uri to grab the data from the endpoint that you need and parse it with JSON.

Requirements: open-uri and json

In the controller:

```
@people = JSON.parse(open("http://api.people.com:3000/people").read, symbolize_names: true)
```

In the view:

```
<% @people.each do |person| %>
    Name:<%= person[:name] %>
    Age:<%= person[:age] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please note that, not explicitly deleting unused Tempfiles can potentially leave behind large amounts of tempfiles on the filesystem until they're garbage collected. It is better to call `open` in a separate line and closing the returned temp after.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can be a good design.

My advice it to read "Service Oriented Design with Ruby And Rails:
[http://www.amazon.com/Service-Oriented-Design-Rails-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321659368](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659368)

It focus on Restful Ruby apps just like your example with an emphasis on scaling and performance. It also investigates different frameworks (Rack, Sinatra, Rails) and the roles they fill well.

Unfortunately I have not implemented this strategy my self (yet!) so I can not give you any first hand advice.