# How to consume a REST API in a Rails 3.1 application?

Tags: api, rest

1. Server is (Java or .net API)
2. Client is (Ruby on rails)

How to call the actions through rails? and How to implement create, edit, update, delete through on rails.

Thanks.

Comment: This is similar to another discussion: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15981836/479017

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you can use ActiveResource in Rails - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html and on Java side expose this through servlets that output JSON.

Comment: I find ActiveResource to be difficult to customize for non-Rails APIs.