# Consuming REST API Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, activeresource, rails-roar

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386232/consuming-rest-api-from-rails-application) question but it's quite old and I feel there's now other alternatives to ARes.

Given that many people seem to think that ActiveResource is kind of outdated and heavyweight, I've looked at [Api Smith](https://github.com/filtersquad/api_smith), [Her](https://github.com/remiprev/her), [Roar](https://github.com/apotonick/roar) and of course ARes.

Which one of these gems would be the most reliable, and future proof alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using lower level libraries like HTTParty or Faraday ? They will cover a lot of the ugly stuff for you (ssl, parsing/serializing jsons and XMLs, logging, adding headers...) and you'll keep complete control of the URLs and the management of data.

Comment: Of course, that's also a viable alternative, API smith is basically HTTParty and Her is built on Faraday with added ORM like conventions, much like ARes. These libraries reduces the boilerplate code a bit but maybe it's not worth it?

Comment: Never found it worth. It's alwas a balance between the avoided boilerplate and the lesser control and configurability.

Answer (score 1):

I found that simply using open-uri and json is a viable option.  Less boilerplate and more control / configurability.

Example:

```
@people = JSON.parse(open("http://api.people.com:3000/people").read, symbolize_names: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Roar gem's purpose is to help you build and deserialize objects and it handles a several different JSON formats like JSON-API, JSON-HAL, etc, XML and it's fairly easy to extend the underlying Representable Gem ( forked from popular ROXML gem). Considering Roar is by far the most popular alternative to ARes, and is part of the much larger Trailblazer Ecosystem ( thou you can use it on it's own) - I would argue Roar is more "future proof". But I might be biased.