# Simplest way to consume Rails REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest

I want to make a simple call using an API. I tried implementing ActiveResource, which may have been deprecated (see here: [Consuming REST API from Rails Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386232/consuming-rest-api-from-rails-application?lq=1)).

I already have an access token for the API, and when I step through the process from the console (see quick start guide: https://github.com/teamsnap/apiv2-docs/wiki/1.-Authentication), I can get things to work (like adding a new team).  However, I can't seem to figure out how to implement it in Rails. I want to start with something simple like displaying my team names on a page - that's it!

Here is the API info: https://github.com/teamsnap/apiv2-docs/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide .

I think since I already have a token (that I got via the command line tutorial), I don't need to include my username and password every time.  This could be incorrect.

If someone could please give me details on how to set this up, I would greatly appreciate it!  I am fairly new to rails, so feel free to give as much info as possible.  Thank you!

EDIT:
Thanks to Uri, it's working. To create a simple test of the API, I created a blank show.html.erb page. In teams_controller.rb, I added Uri's code into a "show" method, and add routes, as set forth below:

**teams_controller.rb**

```
def show
RestClient.post("https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams", '{"team": {"team_name": "Braves", "sport_id": 1, 
  "timezone": "Mountain Time (US & Canada)", "country": "United States", "zipcode": 80302}}',content_type: :json,
   x_teamsnap_token: 'your_token_goes_here_in_quotes')
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'teams/show'
post 'teams/show'
```

To test the api, navigate your browser to localhost:3000/teams/show . This will manually 'fire' the show method for you.  Go back to your Teams Dashboard at Teamsnap (http://go.teamsnap.com/team/dashboard).  You should now have a new team called 'Braves' (see Braves name in code above)!  Now that I know it's working, I can move on to other features like creating teams in my app and sending that information to TeamSnap, instead of hard-coding it as set forth above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rest-client`](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem to make your calls easier (though simple `net/http` would work just as well)

```
RestClient.post("https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams", 
  '{"team": {"team_name": "West Nile Mosquitos", "sport_id": 1, "timezone": "Mountain Time (US & Canada)", "country": "United States", "zipcode": 80302}}',
  content_type: :json, x_teamsnap_token: my_token)
```

Comment: Thanks @Uri! I will give this a try. Can you tell me where this code goes, in the controller?

Comment: no, since I'm not familiar with your application... I guess wherever you need the information...

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Will give it a go and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wrest` gem to easily query web services.

Here's what you need to do

1. Install Wrest gem by specifying `gem 'wrest'` in your Gemfile.
2. To query the web services, use a syntax like so

**[ GET ]**     `https://api.github.com/repos/c42/wrest/issues'.to_uri.get.deserialize`

**[POST]**   `'http://my.api.com'.to_uri.post('YAML encoded body', 'Content-Type' => 'text/x-yaml')`

The best part is that `wrest` also supports caching.